# Azure: Directory has one or more applications that were added by a user or administrator

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

While deleting the azure directory I'm getting the following error:

> Directory has one or more applications that were added by a user or
>   administrator

The only application in that directory is "*Office 365 Management APIs*" which we cannot delete from azure portal. We have to use PowerShell.

So based on article [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/97ff3b1c-4f2f-46c5-8517-8cdc52249fe2/cannot-delete-directory-due-to-office-365-management-apis?forum=WindowsAzureAD) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgolpe/2015/04/30/walkthrough-of-deleting-an-azure-ad-tenant/), I followed all the steps,
but when I try to delete the directory I get above error.

Based on the first link I provided above, there are so many other users also getting the same error after following Microsoft's suggested steps.

Not sure if there is any other way to delete this directory?

Answer (score 0):

For the moment the only solution came from the [article you've mentioned](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgolpe/2015/04/30/walkthrough-of-deleting-an-azure-ad-tenant/):

- Create a "global Admin" user in your Azure AD Tenant.
- Log in once with the newly created user (in order to set up the password).
- User Powershell to delete the applications :

  - Install the [Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant for IT Professionals RTW](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41950)
  - Install the [Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell (64-bit version)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=236297)
  - Open up your PowerShell Command Prompt.
  - Connect to your tenant first with the user you've created:

    ```
    $msolcred = get-credential
    connect-msolservice -credential $msolcred
    ```
  - Delete all non-required apps in the tenant directory (don't worry about the errors):

    ```
    Get-MsolServicePrincipal | Remove-MsolServicePrincipal
    ```
- From the Azure portal:

  - Delete the newly created user.
  - Delete the tenant.

Answer (score 0):

So finally i was able to delete the directory. I was making silly mistake. I followed the same articles i posted above. 
However the issue was, When you select Applications tab on azure portal the default view shows "Application My Company Uses". We had one application created under "Application My Company Owns."
So i just select option "Application My Company Owns" form drop down list, and there was old application, i deleted that and then deleted the directory